# My prefix a trick

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

> My prefix a trick,
>
> My suffix a tick.
>
> My infix heir to a throne,
>
> Overall, I am useless alone.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This took a moment to figure out; especially the *suffix*. However, I'm pretty sure I got it:

> Consonant

*My prefix a trick* - Supplied by: [Joe-You-Know](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/48593/joe-you-know)

> Con is a trick.

*my suffix a tick*

> Ant; there are two ways this can be interpreted. The first is the animal *tick*. In relation to *tick*, *ant*s are looked at as similar with both being *insects* to most; however, this is not the case. [Ants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant) belong to the class *insecta* whereas [ticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick) belong to the class *Arachnida*. The second interpretation is in regards to a clock; more specifically the *ticking* noise it makes. *Ant* is defined as a suffix; *denoting attribution of an action or state*. This definition as a suffix helps relate *ant* to *tick* in the second interpretation.

*My infix heir to a throne*

> Son; in most countries, the first born son is heir to the throne.

*Overall, I am useless alone.*

> Most consonants are useless alone.

Comment: Correct! For the suffix, rot13(V jnf whfg hfvat n jbeq gung pbhyq eryngr gb na nag. Gurer vf ab qrrcre zrnavat ) :)

Comment: I was literally going to guess this, but I got sidetracked :( :( :(

Comment: @casey I would like to refer you to [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69686/hunting-season-is-open) for some examples on how to rot13(eryngr navznyf va n jnl gung pna or sbhaq; jvgu fbzr rssbeg bs pbhefr). In parallel; this was a good riddle, I enjoyed it!

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> conscionable

My prefix a trick,

> A con

my suffix a tick.

> able - I've got nothing here, but I'm pretty sure this is the answer

My infix heir to a throne,

> scion

Overall, I am useless alone.

> conscionable means  Acceptable or permissible according to conscience. It is useless if you don't have a conscience.

Comment: Not the word I was looking for, but very good guess!

Comment: @casey, Am I reasonably close?

Comment: You're getting there. rot13(Lbh jrer pbeerpg sbe bar bs gur yvarf.)

Comment: @casey rot13(juvpu yvar vf pbeerpg)?